# Where does StreamWriter creates text file in Mono Framework - C#

Tags: c#, mono, streamwriter

I created a **C#** application in Visual C#. The application uses StreamWriter to write text files. The path of the text file is given application directory.

```
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + @"\myTExtFile.txt", true);
        sw.Write((Keys)num);
        sw.Close();
```

Now when I run the compiled **.exe** application in Windows, it runs successfully creating the text file. But when I try to run it on Mac with Mono Framework, it doesn't create the text, although it runs successfully without any error.

The application **must** be creating the text file, but I am unable to locate it.

Comment: You should *always* use `System.IO.Path.Combine(...)` to create file paths.  *Never* use string concatenation.

Comment: You have all the tools to figure this out yourself.  Just make a small console app that runs `Console.WriteLine(Application.StartupPath + @"\myTExtFile.txt")`.  Then run it from the same directory as your other app.

Comment: The text file is created successfully in windows, but not in Mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try debugging and looking at the Application.StartupPath property

or:

```
    var fullPath = Path.Combine (Application.StartupPath, "myTExtFile.txt");
    Console.WriteLine (fullPath);
```

BTW: Use Path.Combine vs. string concatenation as it is xplat-based and you do not have to deal with path separators.